# MySql Table where every row has multiple foreign key to one table

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, create-table, denormalization

I have the current situation:

Table1 PackingList:

```
CREATE TABLE `PackingList` (
  `PackingListId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Sku` char(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PartId1` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `PartId2` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId3` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId4` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId5` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId6` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId7` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId8` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId9` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartId10` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PackingListId`),
  KEY `PartId1 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId1`),
  KEY `PartId2 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId2`),
  KEY `PartId3 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId3`),
  KEY `PartId4 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId4`),
  KEY `PartId5 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId5`),
  KEY `PartId6 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId6`),
  KEY `PartId7 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId7`),
  KEY `PartId8 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId8`),
  KEY `PartId9 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId9`),
  KEY `PartId10 <-> PLC_PartId[PartId]` (`PartId10`),
);
```

Table2 (PartId):

```
 CREATE TABLE `PartId` (
  `PartSkuId` int(8) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Content` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Height` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Width` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Depth` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Weight` decimal(7,3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Supplier` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InUse` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `FF_Confirmed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PartSkuId`),
  KEY `Supplier` (`Supplier`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6698 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

given the fact that i have this two tables in which every row of the PackingList table contains multiple ids referring to a row in the PartId table, i would like to get something like a list of PackingList where every row is a relation PackingList (can be duplicate) --> partId :

```
PackingListId PartId
H0001          partId1
H0001 .        partId2
```

and so on.

So far I did some select to get that information together but I didn't get that far, can someone please help me in writing a query with such a result?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to explain how you will get your desired result from your two tables. Maybe instead of using the word `data` as a placeholder for every data item, you should change them to `data01`, `dataa02`, and so forth.

Comment: Hey O. Jones, i edited the question a bit, hope that this is better !

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Maybe add some more sample rows in your table to make your result show fewer `dataxxx` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pro Tip 1**: the more time you take figuring out what your SQL query (or indeed any program) must do, the less time it will take you do it.

This is guesswork. I am answering your question before you edited it. But I believe you want something like this

This gets you the values from t2 mentioned in t1.p1.

```
      SELECT t1.T1_Id, t2.T2_Id, t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
        FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.p1 = T2_Id
```

You then need a mess of these subqueries, one for each `p*` item. You'll take the union of those subqueries.

```
SELECT  T1_Id, T2_Id, c1, c2, c3
  FROM
      SELECT t1.T1_Id, t2.T2_Id, t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
        FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.p1 = T2_Id
 UNION
      SELECT t1.T1_Id, t2.T2_Id, t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
        FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.p2 = T2_Id
 UNION
      SELECT t1.T1_Id, t2.T2_Id, t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.c3
        FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.p3 = T2_Id
ORDER BY T1_Id, T2_Id
```

**Pro Tip 2**: This is harder than it needs to be because your t1 table is *denormalized*. It may be too late to change that in your application, but you should read about it in any case.

Comment: Thanks Your answer is what i was looking for, i know that the table is not normalized, it was not me making a project of the db unfortunately and the table is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Use sub query like

SELECT T1_Id,(SELECT T2_Id FROM Table2) as T2_Id, (SELECT C1 FROM Table2) as C1, (SELECT C2 FROM TAble2) as C2, (SELECT C3 FROM TAble2) as C3 FROM Table1